# Finding everything but null bytes regex

Tags: python, regex

The file I'm trying to analyse is full with a lot of null bytes (`\x00`). The `\S` command (or various other white space commands) do not work. I'm curious as to how I can retrieve everything BUT the null bytes.

If it was possible to do something like `\x01-xFF` (return all values within that byte range) that would work as intended. But as far as I'm aware regex can only search for single bytes instead of a range of bytes. How would one go about returning all strings between the null bytes?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but regexes can search for ranges of characters. For instance `[a-z]` will match any lowercase letter. `[a-z0-9]` will match any lowercase letter or number.

Comment: I was aware of this but thanks anyway. I just wasn't sure if it was possible with bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) method of string to remove `\x00`:

```
your_string.translate(None, '\x00')
```

And for a file you can do :

```
open('in_file.txt').read().translate(None, '\x00')
```

Or you can loop over your lines and apply it on lines!And if you want to split your string you can just use `str.split()` :

```
>>> s='this\x00isat\x00hes'
>>> s.split('\x00')
['this', 'isat', 'hes']
```

Comment: Also a good answer, I was wanting to split up the strings rather than concatenate them all together though.

Comment: @Calibre so you can use `str.split()` checkout the edit!

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to match a non null character is:

```
r"[^\x00]"
```

but what you want is to remove all null characters and the following suffices:

```
s = s.replace("\x00", "")
```

where `s` is the input string.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was trying to match the entire string rather than character by character. `[^\x00]+` works as intended. In the python documentation `^` is listed as 'matches the start of the string' rather than 'NOT'?

Comment: inside brackets `^` has the meaning of not